# Phpmailer doesn't work on wamp on windows server 2008

Tags: server, smtp, wamp, phpmailer

i'm trying to send an email using phpmailer, it works fine on my laptop using xampp localhost server but when i tried to run the php class on my windows server 2008 with wamp installed on it it didn't work.
i already checked if the ssl is enabled from the php.ini

i'm getting this error:

> 2016-09-06 10:01:22    Connection: opening to smtp.mail.yahoo.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2016-09-06 10:01:44  SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060) 2016-09-06 10:01:44    SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
>   here's my code:

```
SendOutlook();
function SendOutlook(){
    //$recipient = 'alghomlas.dk@pg.com';
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $Emp_recipient = "alghomlas.dk@pg.com";
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;                               // Enable verbose    debug output

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";   // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'xxxxxxxxx';                 // SMTP username (server username)
    $mail->Password = 'xxxxx';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom('alghomlas.dk@yahoo.com', 'One');
    $mail->addAddress($Emp_recipient,"dalal alghomlas");     // Add a recipient

    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'test';
    $mail->Body    = "scheduled on your outlook calender";

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit();
    }else {
        echo '<p>Message has been sent</p>';
    }
    echo !extension_loaded('openssl')?"Not Available":"Available";
    AddOutlookEvent($Mng_recipient, $Emp_recipient, $Mng_Name, $Emp_Name, $Date, $Time);

}
```

Comment: i don't if this will help but since i'm using port number 587 i enabled only the outbound rules and not the inbound, should i enable both?

Comment: It helps if you read the docs the error message points you at. It looks like your server is blocked from outbound SMTP connections; doing the checks in the guide will confirm this.

Comment: i already opened the outbound port 587 in my server, still the same error

Comment: It may not be up to you - your ISP may be blocking it. Do the tests like I said and you'll know. We can't do it for you.